# Javascript for changing the value of a non required field

Tags: javascript

Basically, I have the labels of the fields inside the input boxes and use *onblur* and *onclick* to clear the values etc. I also have some javascript to make sure the required files aren't submitted as the label e.g. first name contains the label `First Name*` and I don't want it submitted as `First Name*`.

Where I'm struggling is with the comments box. It isn't a required field so I don't want an alert to pop up, I just want the javascript to change the value to either blank or n/a if it's left as 'comments'. Here is the javascript code I am using to try and achieve this:

```
var comments=document.getElementById('comments').value;
if (comments=="comments")
{
    document.getElementById('comments').value="n/a";
}
```

Comment: please show us your html part .. so that we can help...

Comment: What is happening when your JS runs?

Comment: Here is the HTML

<textarea name="comments" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" id="comments" rows="3" cols="2" maxlength="200" value="comments" onClick="if(this.value == 'comments') { this.value = ''; }" onBlur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'comments'; }" >comments<?php p($_SESSION['form']['formfields']['comments']); ?></textarea>

Comment: I'd recommend using the `placeholder` attribute instead. You can easily find a jQuery Placeholder plugin for older browsers as well. Also if you're doing validation I'd definitely recommend H5Validate which allows you to use proper `required` and `pattern` attributes etc.

Comment: is ur javascript code inside $(document).ready(function(){.....}} ??

Comment: @powerbuoy I would have used placeholder but as far as I'm aware, it doesn't work in IE. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: My code isn't, it's only in function validateForm().
There are other fields in this function that work @bipen

Comment: Think I have just solved my own question...Forgot to return the function in the form tag...whoops - Thanks for all your help though guys

Answer (score 1):

i think your comment field is a textarea.... use

```
document.getElementById('comments').innerText
```

instead

```
document.getElementById('comments').value
```